# Why do we have an additional array of buckets in a hash algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, hash

I've been stepping through the implementation for a Hashset for the .net framework, I am slightly confused by the implementation of it. Here is the `Contains` method:

```
    private int[] m_buckets;
    private Slot[] m_slots;

public bool Contains(T item) {
        if (m_buckets != null) {
            int hashCode = InternalGetHashCode(item);
            // see note at "HashSet" level describing why "- 1" appears in for loop
            for (int i = m_buckets[hashCode % m_buckets.Length] - 1; i >= 0; i = m_slots[i].next) {
                if (m_slots[i].hashCode == hashCode && m_comparer.Equals(m_slots[i].value, item)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        // either m_buckets is null or wasn't found
        return false;
    }


internal struct Slot {
        internal int hashCode;      // Lower 31 bits of hash code, -1 if unused
        internal T value;
        internal int next;          // Index of next entry, -1 if last
    }
```

I understand the first part, get the hash code of the item. Next a loop is started and a suitable index is generated from the hashcode. But then it uses this index to retrieve a value from an array of integers, which it then uses to check if the hashcodes of the values and the values themselves are the same. Why is this? Also, I cannot get my head around the .next property, why is it necessary to store this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several objects may have the same value for *hashCode % m_buckets.Length* even if they have distinct *hashCode* values. Distinct objects may also have the same *hashCode* value (even though it is unlikely).

This is resolved by storing all the objects with the same value for *hashCode % m_buckets.Length* in an array, and then searching for the appropriate element in that array. The reason it compares both the *hashCode* value and the objects themselves is that the comparison of *hashCode* is faster than the comparison of the objects themselves. By doing a cheap check on the hashcodes first we can avoid doing an expensive check on the objects.

The *next* values are stored so that it is possible to enumerate the elements that hash to a single value.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. So m_slots[i].next will keep giving values where the calculation of (hashCode % m_buckets.Length) is equal to the same value. (Suppose "William".GetHashCode() and "Tom".GetHashCode() both equal index '1' when performing the remainder operator on it?